# Elastic Beanstalk worker tier Degraded, SQS daemon keep repeating "init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

The env will be Degraded and no message can't be sent.

Platform is Docker using dockerrun.aws.json. Container is a Django app. I tried with two instance types (I confirmed it from EC2 dashboard) t2.micro t2.small

Sometimes, after deployment, the SQS daemon keep repeating the init like this, CPU usage will be max

```
2022-03-23T07:47:51Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:47:56Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:01Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:07Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:12Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:18Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:23Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:28Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
2022-03-23T07:48:33Z init: initializing aws-sqsd 3.0.3 (2020-11-04)
```

To fix it I need to redeploy the app but it's not always gonna fix it. I thought it's memory issue, but it did work in t2.micro for one time. I wanted to do a memory profiling but looks like too much of a work.

I've tried:

- using previous platform version
- rebuilding the env from scratch

Answer (score 0):

It's because SQS Daemon can not find pid file.
I had same problem and fixed it.

1. Edit /etc/systemd/system/sqsd.service file like below.

```
[Unit]
Description=This is sqsd daemon
PartOf=aws-eb.target

[Service]
User=sqsd
Type=forking

ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "mkdir -p /var/run/aws-sqsd"
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/aws-sqsd start"
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "systemctl show -p MainPID sqsd.service | cut -d= -f2 > /var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid"
ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c "ln -s /var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid /var/pids/sqsd.pid"

ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c "rm -f /var/run/aws-sqsd/default.pid"
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c "rm -f /var/pids/sqsd.pid"
Restart=always

EnvironmentFile=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/ruby_common_env

StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=sqsd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Reload SQS Daemon : systemctl daemon-reload
3. Restart SQS Daemon : systemctl restart sqsd

Comment: Thank you, but turns out my problem was really memory issue. SQS daemon took so much memory. Instance with 1GB RAM is not enough (running Django).